# Why does Chrome throw out my Google Two-Factor Auth "trusted-ness"

Tags: google-account, authentication, multi-factor-auth

I have Google Two-Factor Auth turned on for my account. When I first log into my account, I have to enter a code I receive via SMS. At this point, my computer should be trusted; that is, I should have a cookie which says that I've done this already. Sure enough, if I sign out, I can sign back in without an SMS code.

However, if I restart my browser, Chrome, I am logged out and have to enter the SMS code again.

I haven't changed any of the cookie settings from defaults, and looking at the settings nothing appears to say that it should reject any cookies.

What's going on here?

Comment: One thing to check is Settings > Advanced > Privacy > Content settings ... ensure that "Allow local data to be set (recommended)" is the only option selected. Note that I'm looking at v24. Another link of interest: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30745/limit-google-trusted-computer-auth-cookies-to-30-days

Comment: Yeah, that's set. And I'm on v24 also. Thanks, though!

Comment: Google's version number is in to the 50s nowadays. Is this still an issue for you? Do you use any third-party tools to manage your cookies?